# What is a good way to handle contractions and possessive apostrophes when doing topic modeling?

Tags: computational-linguistics

I'm doing topic modeling with LDA. As input to LDA I'm using a tokenized corpus. I was wondering what's a good way to handle contractions and possessive apostrophes. Right now words like can't and John's are tokenized to [can, t] and [john, s]. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I see no reason to close this question, and I think it is also clear (to somenone who has some experience with LDA or topic modelling in general.

Comment: @jknappen Thank you! This is exactly the kind of question that should be on stack exchange because it's the kind of phrase that someone is going to google.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply lemmatisation first and run the topic model on the lemmata.

You can use a different tokenisation that tokenises *John's* as [John] ['s] and add 's to the stopword list.

You can probably do more creative things, be sure to document what you have done to your corpus to make your results as reproducible as possible (note also that topic models aren't unique, you may want to try different random seeds and for a reproducible topic model you need to keep the random seed as well).